# std::transform in Visual Studio fails using own iterators

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++, c++11, compiler-errors

In a bigger project, I defined some class which defines its own iterator in a very minimalistic way. Up to now I gave my code gcc and clang, they ate it and were very happy after compiling.

Today I tried to port my project to MSVC.....
Well....

After realizing that MSVC doesn't support some stuff like snprintf or noexcept keyword, I'm stuck at the following piece. Actually I think I know what's going wrong, but I'd like to know why MSVC acts this way and if there are any "easy" ways to solve this problem.

Here is a minimalistic example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test {
public:
    Test(size_t size) : _size(size) {

    };

    class Iterator {
    public:
        Iterator& operator ++() {
            _position++;
            return *this;
        }

        size_t operator *() {
            return _position;
        }

        bool operator !=(const Iterator &rhs) {
            return _position != rhs._position;
        }
    private:
        friend class Test;
        Iterator(size_t position) : _position(position) {};
        size_t _position;
    };

    Iterator begin() {
        return Iterator(0);
    }

    Iterator end() {
        return Iterator(_size);
    }

private:
    size_t _size;
};

int main()
{

    Test t(10);

    for (auto val : t) // however, this works with MSVC
    {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<size_t> out(10);

    // Here it crashes
    std::transform(t.begin(), t.end(), out.begin(), [] (size_t i) {
        return i;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

This code successfully compiles with clang or gcc.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/iVLib56x)'s the compiler output of MSVC (sorry for the german compiler output, I'm new to Windows and I even don't know how to change the language... To be honest it took me days to install Windows -.-)

So let's analyze what's going wrong.

MSVC claims about some missing types like 'iterator_category' and many many other things.
But why does it do that? All types that are used by 'std::transform()' can actually be deduced by the return types of the members of the Iterator class and I suppose that this is the way how clang or gcc are working.

I don't want to write down all those types and definitions. If I would do so, the Iterator would be bigger than the underlying class itself!

Comment: Your iterator is missing some typedefs..

Comment: Yes I know! But why do I need them? All types can be deduced. And GCC and Clang compile it.

Comment: `iterator_traits<your_iterator_type>` is required to provide some types such as the `iterator_category`. The primary `iterator_traits` template tries to define those types by looking for nested types in `your_iterator_type`. Your iterator doesn't provide those nested types, hence it does not fulfill the Iterator concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: inherit from `std::iterator<input_iterator_tag, size_t>`

The problem is that MSVC doesn't know that your iterator is <strike>a forward</strike> an input iterator. This isn't deducable from return types.

Comment: That's it! Got it working with that. But i still don't entirely understand why this is necessary. Maybe it could be useful to have a deeper look inside the c++ standard to get a better understanding of how iterators work exactly.

Comment: Since the return type of `operator*` is not a reference to (possibly `const`) `value_type`, `Test::Iterator` is an input iterator, not a forward iterator.